# How to pass lines from file to input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

If I have a simple program that I would like to test:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = int(input())
    print(a+2)
```

With an input file

```
3
1
9
4
```

How can I launch python and point out to read lines from the input file without modifying the solution program?

Comment: Note: This code won't work on Python 3 at all. `input` always returns a `str` on Python 3, and you're assuming it will be an `int`. You'd need to wrap each use of `input()` in `int()` to make this work on Python 3. It would work (but be more dangerous) on Python 2 because `input()` on Python 2 behaves equivalently to `eval(input())` on Python 3.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, it was just a quick example, should be fixed now

Comment: What is the use case in your actual program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your shell, but a common solution for standard Linux/macOS is:

```
python program.py < file
```